# Rails Migration: Remove constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I have a table in a Rails application which (in schema.rb) looks like:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
   t.string "name", :null=>false
   t.string "address", :null=>false
end
```

I would like to write a rails migration to allow nulls for the address field. i.e. after the migration the table looks like this:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
   t.string "name", :null=>false
   t.string "address"
end
```

What do I need to do to remove the constraint?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Not sure you can call `t.address`? Anyway... I would use `change_column` like so

```
change_column :users, :address, :string, :null => true
```

Docs...
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column

Answer (score 308):

In Rails 4+ in order to remove not-null constraint, you can use [`change_column_null`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null):

```
change_column_null :users, :address, true
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? If you glance at the source code for the function, you see nothing but: `raise NotImplementedError, "change_column_null is not implemented"`

Comment: have used it in postgresql. rails defines it in the database specific adapter
see [postgres](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter/SchemaStatements/change_column_null), [mysql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractMysqlAdapter/change_column_null). can search for others in [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/search?query=change_column_null). 
So, will have to check the database adapter for support, in case anyone gets a `NotImplementedError`

Comment: Upvote!  Here is the link to the [Rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns)  as well.

Comment: This should be the selected answer