# How to drop a fk constraint in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following situation in production:

My `PersonalInfo` model was created using `t.references :user, foreign_key: true, index: true, unique: true` to model `Users`. However, `PersonalInfo` became polymorfic, with this migration:

```
class AddInfoOwnerToPersonalInfos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    rename_column :personal_infos, :user_id, :info_owner_id
    add_column :personal_infos, :info_owner_type, :string

    add_index :personal_infos, [ :info_owner_type, :info_owner_id]

    PersonalInfo.update_all(info_owner_type: 'User')

    change_column :personal_infos, :info_owner_type, :string, null: false
  end

  def down
    rename_column :personal_infos, :info_owner_id, :user_id
    remove_column :personal_infos, :info_owner_type
  end
end
```

The problem:

Still remain a fk constraint in database:

`ALTER TABLE ONLY public.personal_infos
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_796da13f22 FOREIGN KEY (info_owner_id) REFERENCES public.users(id);`

How could I build a migration to remove safely this constraint? (I believe no constraint is needed in polymorphic associations, only the index)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Migration: Remove constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682068/rails-migration-remove-constraint)

Comment: @MrTheWalrus not a duplicate. That question is a about making the column nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if foreign_key_exists?(:personal_infos, :users) 
  remove_foreign_key(:personal_infos, :users)    
end
```

See:

- [Rails API: remove_foreign_key](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_foreign_key)